# How to get this sprite class to work with my main loop (Pygame)

Tags: python, sprite, pygame

I cannot get my sprite Ball class to get the values of the KEYDOWN/KEYUP events to update itself from the "else" statement in the main loop. Here is the code for the main loop and the ball class:

```
class Ball():
    def  __init__(self):
        global ball
        ball = pygame.sprite.Sprite()
        ball.image = pygame.image.load('red_ball.png').convert()
        ball.rect = ball.image.get_rect()
        ball.image.set_colorkey((white))

    def event_handle(self, event):
        x,y = 285, 430
        m_x, m_y = 0,0
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_a:
                    m_x = -4
            elif event.key == K_d:
                    m_x = +4
            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_a:
                        m_x = 0
                elif event.key == K_d:
                        m_x = 0

        x+= m_x
        y+= m_y
        if x > 640:
            x = 0
        if x < 0:
            x = 640
    def update(self):
        screen.blit(ball.image,(x,y))
        pygame.display.update()

def main():
    m_x, m_y = 0,0
    while True:
        ball = Ball()
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            else:
                ball.event_handle(event)
        ball.update()
        pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read further than lign 1... That ball should inherit from sprite.Sprite

as I said somewhere else you should read some tutorials. I don't have the time to find a good one about sprites, but if I found it once, you should be able to find it too. Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have this:

```
if key down: 
    if k=a:
         do stuff
    if k=s:
         do stuff
     ***if k up:
          do stuff***
```

You need to move if k up outside of the if key down. Right now you are saying that if the key is up, and it is down, then do what you want it to when the key is down.